# How to mount a device without a password

Tags: linux, unix, mount

I am using the following command in a script to mount a device. However whenever I run it, it prompts for a password.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //xxx/lon-hsv/BT/APPOPS/Qlikview /mnt/appops -o user=nobody,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nounix,noserverino
```

How do I modify the command so that it does not ask for a password?

Comment: Run the script with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify configure `sudo` (through the `/etc/sudoers` file) to allow some users to use this command without a password. For security reasons, when you do this type of thing, you should be **as restrictive as possible** (ie do **not** allow *all* users to use the `mount` command without a password; maybe even create a second script for the mounting task only, and the execution of this script via `sudo` only for some users).

Read the relevant manpages (`man sudo` and `man sudoers`).

Comment: I have the following sudo permissions: user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: should that not be enough?

Comment: This will work, but this is ***really*** insecure. Basically you allow everyone to run anything as any user without a password. **This is not recommended**.

Comment: but it still asks for a password?

Comment: Then it's not `sudo` that asks for a password, but the `mount.cifs` command (automatically called by `mount -t cifs`). Check the permissions of your network share.

Comment: which file has permissions for network share, i tried smb.conf but it doesnt exist on my machine